# Reading barcode by using ZXing-cpp and Leptonica

Tags: c++, zxing, leptonica

I'm interested in reading barcode by using ZXing-cpp and Leptonica libraries. And I see in Github (https://github.com/creatale/node-dv) having a project regarding to this topic.
I've read source code and seen in zxing.cc (https://github.com/creatale/node-dv/blob/master/src/zxing.cc), class PixSource using a method:

PixSource::PixSource(Pix* pix, bool take) { if (take) { pix_ = pix; } else { pix_ = pixConvertTo8(pix, 0); } }

And I don't understand about these statements. I think that input data of image (which will be processed by ZXing core) must be converted to 8 depth (GrayScale format)
Is it correct? If you know why, please help me!